# NetTcpBinding - Self-Hosted WCF - Can't get client connected

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

Trying to get a simple demo of NetTcpBinding working in order to expand it into another project.

Architecture:  2 console apps (1 host/server, 1 client) and 1 type library project.  Both console apps have a reference to the type library project.

**Host application:**

```
class Program
{ 
    static void Main()
    {
        var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None)
        {
            PortSharingEnabled = true
        };

        var netTcpAdddress = new Uri("net.tcp://127.0.0.1:1234/HelloWorldService/");

        var tcpHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), netTcpAdddress);
        tcpHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloWorld), netTcpBinding, "IHelloWorld");

        tcpHost.Open();
        Console.WriteLine($"tcpHost is {tcpHost.State}.  Press enter to close.");

        Console.ReadLine();
        tcpHost.Close();
    }
}


public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorld
{
    public void HelloWorld()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }

    public void WriteMe(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"WriteMe: {text}");
    }
}
```

**Client application:**

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter when the service is opened.");
        Console.ReadLine();


        var endPoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://127.0.0.1:1234/HelloWorldService/");
        var binding = new NetTcpBinding ();
        var channel = new ChannelFactory<IHelloWorld>(binding, endPoint);
        var client = channel.CreateChannel();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoking HelloWorld on TcpService.");
            client.HelloWorld();
            Console.WriteLine("Successful.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**Type Library:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloWorld
{
    [OperationContract]
    void HelloWorld();

    [OperationContract]
    void WriteMe(string text);
}
```

I believe I have all necessary services installed and running:

[image]

Obviously I'm trying to do all the config at runtime.

I consistently get this error message on the client:

Invoking HelloWorld on TcpService.

> Exception: There was no endpoint listening at
>   net.tcp://127.0.0.1:1234/HelloWorldService/ that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details. Press enter to quit.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Is there an inner exception?  Is the host application running when you run the client?  Is the host application running under an account that has admin priveleges?

Comment: InnerException is empty.  It is running with admin privileges, and fails (properly) when run without.  FWIW:  I had this running with http bindings, but tried to switch to netTcp because I didn't want to have to use admin privs.  May have to give up on that idea, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service is exposing the endpoint at address:

`net.tcp://127.0.0.1:1234/HelloWorldService/IHelloWorld`

but your client is connecting to:

`net.tcp://127.0.0.1:1234/HelloWorldService/`

You'll also need to set the client `NetTcpBinding` `SecurityMode` the same as the server (`None`).

Comment: You nailed it!  I didn't realize the path was being extended with the interface name.    Thank you!   For the readers:  Adding Security = {Mode = SecurityMode.None} to my binding initializer and setting endPoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://127.0.0.1:1235/HelloWorldService/IHelloWorld") solved it all!